# Measuring time on section of page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

We all know that with Google analytics we can measure visitors' time on page quite easily, but is there maybe a way to measure how long the user was on some specific section of a page?
For example, could I somehow get the amount of time a user has spent looking at the first half of my page and compare it to the time a user has spent looking at the second half of the page?

Does anyone have any kind of experience with anything similar? Does G-A offer this "out of the box" or can I maybe create the functionality myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics has a function for [user timings](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings). You could start a timer when the page loads and stop it e.g. when the user has scrolled past a certain point in your page, and then send the value via user timings:

```
ga('send', 'timing', 'Section Times', 'Section A', 345);
```